# Cannot run Android SDK manager. How to run SDKmanager.bat?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, mobile

[image: enter image description]

When I try to run `sdkmanager.bat` an empty command prompt opens and disappears immediately. I am not able to install the SDK and set it up with Eclipse because of that. Online tutorials seem to have an `SDKmanager.exe` which I don't see at all. Only the batch file shows up which I can't run.

Answer (score 1):

`sdkmanager.bat` is a command-line tool. Its interface is described in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager).

You are probably looking for GUI tool. It was available in older Android SDK versions, but it [was removed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63970413) in 2017. So the only way to use GUI is to use it from some IDE (e.g. Android Studio)